# BS4 error in Python script.. runs fine in PyCharm but not in OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I'm running a PY4E script in PyCharm community 2020.. within the IDE it runs correctly however when I attempt to call the script externally is tracebacks with a BS4 issue.

Code and traceback here: https://bpa.st/QLTA

The code dir contains bs4 but I have installed bs4 via pip already.. also html5lib but neither helped matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I did not Google well enough: answered here: https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl/issues/554 back in 2016.

Solution is to downgrade HTML5lib to 1.0b8